# sourcing one script within another

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm missing something here.
We have one script to set several environment variables:

firstscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/novus/jdk/jdk1.7.0_67
echo "exported"
```

These variables are important to other scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

What I've been doing that is working is from the shell, sourcing the first script and calling the second.  I'm trying to combine the two scripts into one.
I think the second script should look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
eval firstscript.sh
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I've tried this with eval, I've tried this with source, I've tried this without either eval or source, no matter what i do, the variables exported in first script aren't found in secondscript.

I've also tried it without firstscript exporting, just setting variables within the shell.  That too isn't working.  Like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
JAVA_HOME=/novus/jdk/jdk1.7.0_67
echo "exported"
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be working with `export` and `source`. Here is a test run in case you may have missed something :

```
$ echo 'export var1=defined' > sourced_script.sh
$ echo 'source ./sourced_script.sh; echo $var1' > main_script.sh
$ chmod +x main_script.sh
$ ./main_script.sh
defined
```

There are at least two important points :

- the variables must be `export`ed, otherwise they will not be available outside of the context defining them
- the `source` must be executed in the same shell that will use the variables.

For the second point, if you were for example to execute the following command :

```
(source first_script.sh; echo $JAVA_HOME) ; echo $JAVA_HOME
```

only the first echo would print the variable defined in `first_script.sh`, since the export would only impact the subshell it is run in.

Comment: thats what I needed, thank you.  
I was in fact doing something wrong.  Thanks for the right example.